# How to add marker in offline map using mapbox SDK

Tags: android, dictionary, offline, mapbox, marker

I am using mapbox SDK and have used mbtile as offline map display.
So, now i want to add marker on that map.
Hows it possible?

Comment: Be clear with your question. You need solution for iOS or Android ?

Comment: markerOptions = new markerOptions(lat,long);

Comment: @BSavaliya ... have u done this...do u remember how you have done ?

Comment: @Priya ... you can refer my answer

Comment: thank  you BSavaliya, do you have any idea about searching option in offline stored map.. ?

Comment: @Priya : sorry don't have any idea regarding search functionality in offline map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i got the solution :

```
public void placeMarker() {
        alMarkerGT = new ArrayList<Marker>();
        marker = new Marker("my Marker", "", latLng);
        marker.setMarker(activity.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.map_pin));
        mv.addMarker(marker);
        alMarkerGT.add(marker);
        itemizedIconOverlayGT = new ItemizedIconOverlay(activity, alMarkerGT,
                new OnItemGestureListener<Marker>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, Marker item) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, Marker item) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        mv.addItemizedOverlay(itemizedIconOverlayGT);
    }
```